# moving an object in relation to another in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Ok so i have a character_mc that moves on mouse click, a logtxt dyanamic text box and a mc named $box. The camera follows the character and when the log and $ boxes are staying put.

I want them to stay on the same point on the stage(meaning I want them to stay at the same place on the camera) I was wondering what i might do for this? I have tried to put them in a movie clip but it doesn't really seam like it worked well so i discarded the idea.

Heres the code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        // player

        public var characterEndMC:MovieClip = new charEndMC();

        //box
        private var boxAmount:Number=0;
        private var boxLimit:Number=20;
        private var _root:Object;
        //$txt
        public var money:int=0;
        public var gold:int=0;

        //$$
        public var testnumber:Number=1;
        //enemy1
        private var e01Amount:Number=0;
        private var e01Limit:Number=2;



        public function Main() {


            $box.click$.move$.buttonMode=true;
            $box.click$.clickmini$.buttonMode=true;


            character_mc["charAngle"]=0;
            character_mc["moveX"]=0;
            character_mc["moveY"]=0;
            character_mc["walkSpeed"]=7;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, charMove);

            //box add listener
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);

            //moneybox
            $box.click$.move$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startmoving$);
            $box.click$.move$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopmoving$);
            $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);



        }



        public function charLoop(event:Event) {
            if (character_mc.hitTestPoint(character_mc["charEnd"].x,character_mc["charEnd"].y,true)) {


                character_mc["moveX"]=0;
                character_mc["moveY"]=0;
                this.removeChild(character_mc["charEnd"]);
                character_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, charLoop);



            }


            for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
                this.getChildAt(i).x-=character_mc["moveX"];
                this.getChildAt(i).y-=character_mc["moveY"];

            }

            character_mc.x+=character_mc["moveX"]+.05;
            character_mc.y+=character_mc["moveY"]+.05;


        }

        public function lookAtMouse() {
            var characterMC:MovieClip=character_mc;
            characterMC["charAngle"] = Math.atan2(this.mouseY - characterMC.y, this.mouseX - characterMC.x) / (Math.PI / 180);

            characterMC.rotation=characterMC["charAngle"];
        }
        public function charMove(event:MouseEvent) {
            lookAtMouse();
            this.addChild(characterEndMC);
            characterEndMC.x=this.mouseX;
            characterEndMC.y=this.mouseY;

            character_mc["charEnd"]=characterEndMC;
                        character_mc["charEnd"].visible = false;


            character_mc["moveX"]=Math.cos(character_mc["charAngle"]*Math.PI/180)*character_mc["walkSpeed"];
            character_mc["moveY"]=Math.sin(character_mc["charAngle"]*Math.PI/180)*character_mc["walkSpeed"];



            character_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, charLoop);


        }


        //boxadding
        private function eFrame(event:Event):void {
            if (boxAmount<boxLimit) {
                boxAmount++;

                var _box:Box=new Box  ;
                _box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,boxclick);
                _box.buttonMode=true;
                _box.y=Math.random()* (1000 + _box.height/2);

                _box.x=Math.random()* (1000 + _box.width/2);

                addChild(_box);

            }
            if (e01Amount<e01Limit) {
                e01Amount++;

                var Enemy1:enemy01=new enemy01  ;
                Enemy1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, en01click);
                Enemy1.buttonMode=true;
                Enemy1.y=Math.random()*stage.stageHeight;

                Enemy1.x=Math.random()*stage.stageWidth;

                addChild(Enemy1);

            }

        }

        public function boxclick(event:MouseEvent):void {

            var _box:Box=event.currentTarget as Box;
            logtxt.appendText("You collected " + testnumber +  " boxes" + "\n" );
            character_mc["moveX"] = _box.y + 40 + (height / 2);
            character_mc["moveY"]=_box.x;


            logtxt.scrollV=logtxt.maxScrollV;
            var randVal$:Number=Math.random();
            if (randVal$>=0.49) {
                money+=100;
            } else if (randVal$ <= 0.50 && randVal$ >= 0.15) {
                money+=200;
            } else if (randVal$ <= 0.14 && randVal$ >= 0.02) {
                gold+=10;
            } else if (randVal$ == 0.01) {
                money+=200;
                gold+=20;
            }


            testnumber++;



            boxAmount--;


            $box.box$in.box$insins.Moneytxt.text=String(money);
            $box.box$in.box$insins.Goldtxt.text=String(gold);
            removeChild(_box);

        }

        private function startmoving$(event:MouseEvent):void {
            $box.startDrag();
        }
        private function stopmoving$(event:MouseEvent):void {
            $box.stopDrag();
        }
        private function c$mini(event:MouseEvent):void {
            $box.click$.move$.visible=false;
            $box.box$in.visible=false;

            $box.y=200;
            $box.x=100;
            $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reclickbox$);
            $box.click$.clickmini$.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);


        }
        private function reclickbox$(event:MouseEvent):void {
            $box.click$.clickmini$.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, c$mini);
            $box.click$.clickmini$.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reclickbox$);
            $box.y=70;
            $box.x=250;
            $box.click$.move$.visible=true;
            $box.box$in.visible=true;
        }

        public function scroll_text( n:Number ) {

            logtxt.scrollV = Math.round( ( logtxt.maxScrollV - 1 ) * n ) + 1;
        }

        public function en01click(event:MouseEvent) {

        }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is put all related objects on their own layer using Sprites.

It's a bit difficult to understand what you are doing in your example but here's
a quick example of what you can do :

```
// Add all your game related objects to this Sprite - characters, enemies etc.
private var cameraContainer:Sprite = new Sprite
// Add all your hud objects to this Sprite - logtxt, $box etc.
private var hudContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

public function Main() {
    cameraContainer.addChild(character_mc);
    cameraContainer.addChild(enemy01);
    cameraContainer.addChild(enemy02);
    ...

    hudContainer.addChild(logtxt);
    hudContainer.addChild($box);
}

public function charLoop(event:Event) {
    // Here you should not move all the objects relative to the player but instead
    // move the player and then move the camera relative to the player
    character_mc.x += character_mc['moveX'];
    character_mc.y += character_mc['moveY'];

    // Reposition the camera and everything else will move
    // - Add half the screen size to centre the player on the screen
    cameraContainer.x = -character_mc.x + halfScreenWidth;
    cameraContainer.y = -character_mc.y + halfScreenHeight;
}
```

Comment: I dont really get it could you explain.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?